# disable items of wpf combobox if exist in mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf

I have following combobox in xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="unn" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="unn_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Whenever selection is changed it will perform checking on database if the item already exist there. If Already exist then i want disable selection of the item.

This how i am checking on the database:

```
public void chk()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(accessStr))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new MySqlCommand("select count(1) as value from tbl1 where productID=" + unid + " and " + "month(current_date) = month(entryDate)", connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ret = reader.GetInt32(0);

            }

            If(ret==1) {MessageBox.show("Data Already Exist")};

        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to make an item not select-able.

Comment: What you mean by "disable"? not showing it or... ?

Comment: What is the exact problem with your current code?

Comment: X39, Disable mean, Not select able !

Comment: @kodr: So you want to disable the selection of an item after it has already been selected? Why don't you query the database once and then disable all items that are returned from that query instead of querying the database each time you select a new value in the ComboBox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disallow/Block selection of disabled combobox item in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889963/disallow-block-selection-of-disabled-combobox-item-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rollback the selection.

```
private bool reverting;

private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)e.Source;
    if (reverting) return;
    bool revert = true | false; // true or false
    if (revert)
    {
        reverting = true;
        comboBox.SetCurrentValue(Selector.SelectedItemProperty, e.RemovedItems.Count != 0 ? e.RemovedItems[0] : null);
        reverting = false;
    }
}
```