# DataBinding: Disable ComboBox Item

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889963/disallow-block-selection-of-disabled-combobox-item-in-wpf) to my case. Only difference is that my `ComboBox` is taking its items from an enum list.

I always got a binding expression error to the property "IsProgrammabile" in the `ComboBox` style.

My code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SchedaSelezionata.ListaIngressi}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="NR." DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Numero}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="FUNCTION" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={helpers:EnumBindingSource {x:Type models:INGRESSI}}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Funzione}"
                            ToolTip="{Binding Descrizione}" IsEnabled="{Binding ConfigurabileDaUtente}" Width="150" >
                            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=IsProgrammabile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Note that the "IsProgrammabile" property belongs to same object as the other properties (Numero, Funzione, Descrizione, ConfigurabileDaUtente).
Setting the `AncestorType` to `GridView` or `ListView` doesn't help.

Can you provide the solution and explain me what I do not understand in this context?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What binding is not working?

Comment: The binding to disable the combobox item, i.e. to the property IsProgrammabile. I thought it was pretty obvious. My mistake

Comment: But the binding to the ConfigurabileDaUtente property works? Or why are you trying to disable the ComboBox itself and individual items?

Comment: Everything works perfectly but the ItemContainerStyle section. I want the combobox to show all the items, but some of the items should not be selectable (i.e. they should be disabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComboBox` itself has no property named `IsProgrammabile` but its `DataContext` may have so you should add "DataContext." to the binding path:

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsProgrammabile, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}"/>
```