# Disable selection of drop down items in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, styles

I have a comboBox that is styled to have rows of text blocks and check boxes to allow user to check a list of different things. What I am attempting to do is disable selection of a row in the the combobox.

**My View Code:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding HeaderList}" 
    IsSelected="False"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Height="10"
    x:Name="ComboBox">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}"/>
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**Here is a picture of my Drop Down:**

[image]

**Here is a picture of what I don't want:**

[image]

I want to disable the ability for the user to select a specific row, but keep the ability for them to select various check boxes in the drop down. Is there a way to style this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disallow/Block selection of disabled combobox item in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889963/disallow-block-selection-of-disabled-combobox-item-in-wpf)

Comment: @swamy I saw this but I couldn't quite figure out how to implement this in my already overridden data template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, i solved it by using a `ToggleButton` in combination with a `Popup` (instead of using a `ComboBox`)

**Note:** Not tested

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="filterButton" />
<Popup x:Name="popup" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    StaysOpen="False"
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=filterButton}"
    IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=filterButton,Path=IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HeaderList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>                                    
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Popup>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. I just changed some of the styling to make it look a little better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the selectedindex of your combobox to -1 in the selectionchanged event

```
private void myComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```