# Can I disable the first item a WPF combobox within xaml code?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, isenabled

Consider the following combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Presets.VolumePresetList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding VolumePresetSelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10, 10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            MinWidth="150">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding PresetName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" BorderThickness="0" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The first Item of the combobox is a default preset with a corresponding default name in the textbox. The user therefore shouldn't be able to make input to this first item - thus I want to disable the textbox of the first item.

I know I could just run a function in the constructor of the containing class or the viewmodel, which disables the textbox on the first index, however I'm wondering if this is possible directly within the xaml code (which I would find a more elegant way of doing such static things).

Comment: Did you look at this stackoverflow question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889963/disallow-block-selection-of-disabled-combobox-item-in-wpf

Comment: @KevinCook As far as I understand the answer in this question uses again databinding to handle the IsEnabled value in the viewmodel, right? I wondering of there is a xaml-only approach, where I can disable items based on their index.

Comment: You would have to specify a `CompositeColelction` as the itemsSource in xaml and then add `ComboBoxItem` with `IsHitTestVisible` set to false. Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the fact that the **PreviousData** RelativeSource will return `null` for the first element of a collection. Knowing that you can add a **DataTrigger** to your DataTemplate to set the `IsEnabled` property of the `TextBox` to false.

Here is a simplified version of the `ItemTemplate` with a `PreviousData` binding:

```
       <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="TextBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Just tested out this approach and it is working fine so far. Only thing I can think of, is that in case a new item is inserted at the first index, we get two disabled items. Anywho, as discussed with XAMIMAX above, datatriggers are the way to go - marked it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a composite collection with `DataBinding` for `ListView` but the logic will be the same:

```
<ListView SelectedValue="{Binding youVMPropertyHere}">
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ListViewItem IsHitTestVisible="False">Default Item</ListViewItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsPresetLists}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
<!-- Where-->
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Presets.VolumePresetList}" x:Key="cvsPresetLists"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

This way you can have the first item to be not selectable. I would also use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: Hmm, so if I understand it correctly, the default item in your example is not bound to the the `PresetList` in the ViewModel at all, correct?

Comment: Yup, it is a completely separate object.

Comment: Ok, It makes sense in general, but is not applicable in my case since each Item of the source list is a class object holding several properties (which are used as datacontext for a different usercontrol) The presetname is just one property of this class. 
I hope this makes remotely sense ;)
I will mark your reply as answer anyway, since I it comes closest to what I want to achieve - Thanks!

Comment: Is it because your collection holds the default value? You could also use a template selector, and dish out a `read only` control, if that makes sense?

Comment: (1/2) The source of my combobox is a `ObservableCollection<PresetModel>`. The Presetname is one property of the `PresetModel` class. If the user selects one item of the combobox, the data of the corresponding `PresetModel` is displayed and can be changed by the user. In case of the first item (the default one) I want to prevent the user from being able to change the Presetname. So only if the index of the item is 0 I want the textbox in the datatemplate to be disabled. Currently I handle this simply by binding the `Textbox.IsEnabled` tag to the ViewModel and set it there.

Comment: (2/2) I was wondering if one could do the same thing from within the xaml code, since this is a static thing (as it is always the first index and it will always be disabled and all other items will always be enabled). My current implementation works just fine, I was just curious if it could be done using xaml only. 
Hope, this explains a bit better :)

Comment: You could use a `DataTrigger`? Get the value of the selected index and if it is `0` then set the enabled property to `false`. Does that makes sense? You would use that in the `DataTemplate.resources`.