# WPF get selected ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am facing quite opposite problem than most people - I can get `SelectedItem`'s `DataContext` but not the item itself (the `ComboBoxItem`):

```
private void TypeComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (sender is ComboBox comboBox)
   {
      //always null, fetches UserType object instead (which is the DataContext )
      ComboBoxItem selectedComboBoxItem = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem; 
   }
}
```

I have also tried accessing `ItemContainerGenerator` but it always returns `null` as well:

```
private void TypeComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (sender is ComboBox comboBox)
   {
      comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true; //attempt to force item generation
      comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
      comboBox.UpdateLayout();
      comboBox.ApplyTemplate();
      //also always null no matter what
      var item = comboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(comboBox.SelectedItem);
   }
}
```

how can I get the currently selected `ComboBoxItem`?

Comment: If you mean the name of the item, try `comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: What makes you think `SelectedItem` is a `ComboBoxItem`? What's the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox`? What does `comboBox.SelectedItem` return?

Comment: @mm8 It is not `ComboBoxItem` I wanted to emphasize have an oposite problem than usual: have DataContext, want FrameworkElement. ItemsSource is list of `UserType`. I need to access one of the `ComboBoxItem`'s visual properties.

Comment: @mm8 i am calling it in `TypeComboBox_SelectionChanged` handler. Included whole snippet, rather than just the changed part.

Comment: There is no visual container until the dropdown has been opened. When do you need it and why?

Comment: @mm8 there seems to be no visual container even after opening it (once). I need to read if currently selected item is disabled, and if so, select nearest valid option, especially when the change occured through keyboard interaction (whithout popup open). Accessing the container *while* it is open seems to do the trick. Still looking for better solution - without possible flicker.

Comment: There is no container when the `ComboBox` is closed.

Comment: That sounds as a problem, care to elaborate on the solution while popup is closed?

Answer (score 0):

It appears `UpdateLayout()`/`comboBox.ApplyTemplate()`  ensure `ItemContainerGenerator` method works only if the `comboBox.IsDropDownOpen` is currently `true`:

```
private void TypeComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (sender is ComboBox comboBox)
   {
      comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
      comboBox.UpdateLayout();
      comboBox.ApplyTemplate();
      var item = comboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(comboBox.SelectedItem);
      comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
      //close after geting item ^^^^^
   }
}
```

This contradicts my [original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30121588) on ComboBox Items `ItemContainerGenerator`.